# Count the number of tables in the sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I need a count of the tables that are currently in my sqlite database. Tried searching but did not get any direct method.

I tried this method in my DbHelper.

```
public int countTables() {
    int count = 0;
    String SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'";
    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_TABLES, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

        count++;
        getReadableDatabase().close();

    }
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

But this method gives me a wrong count. I have only 3 tables in my DB, but this method returns count as 5. What could be wrong with this method. Is there any direct method to get the count.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your method is fine, you could even use `SELECT count(*) ...`. But there are two tables created automatically `android_metadata` and `sqlite_sequence`, simply takes these into account: 5 - 2 = 3 tables that you created.

Or since Squonk provided excellent documentation about when [`sqlite_sequence`](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is created and when it might *not* exist, I recommend this query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence';
```

**A few pointers to shorten your code**

All of this:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

Can be accomplished like this:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
```

Cursor.moveToNext() return true if the next row exists. If a new cursor is not empty moveToNext() will return true and set this index on the first position. When `cursor.isAfterLast() == true`, moveToNext() returns false.

But if you simply want to count how many rows are in the Cursor use:

```
int count = cursor.getCount();
```

Lastly, store your writable database in a variable.

```
getReadableDatabase().close();
```

I haven't tested this, but if getReadableDatabase() returns a new SQLiteDatabase object each time then you are simply closing this new database as soon as you have created it... I would close the database *once* and I would close it *after* I have closed all of the Cursors I retrieved from it.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
...

database.close();
```

If you are using a lot of queries consider opening your database in onResume() and closing it in onPause().

Comment: +1 I was going to mention `sqlite_sequence` in a comment on the question but couldn't think of what the other could be as I was looking at a non-Android SQLite DB on my Windows machine.

Comment: One thing to consider (from SQLite docs) *"The sqlite_sequence table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column is created."*. Although using `AUTOINCREMENT` is very common, that statement suggests if no tables use it, then `sqlite_sequence` won't exist. Ideally the OP needs to also cycle through the cursor rowset and compare table names - PITA I know but it would be the only way to be 100% certain.

Comment: Good find on when and why the `sqlite_sequence` table is created, I'll have to remember that and I updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

## Find count and table names

### find count

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select count(*) from sqlite_master as tables where type='table'");
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
```

### retrieve table names

```
ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("select name from sqlite_master as tables where type='table'");
    while(rs2.next())
    {
          String tid = rs2.getString(1);
          System.out.println(tid);
    }
    rs.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
              vvvvvv
SELECT * FROM YourDataBaseName.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
```

Just put your DatabseName as shown.