# Calculate the number of tables in a database sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I could not find a way to calculate with JAVA the number of tables in a database and a system to scroll.

I had a matrix M of size 100000 columns x 100 lines that I had to break up copying of databases on multiple tables for a variety of reasons that I'm there to explain.
Now I have to read the database to reload on matrix M2, where M2 = M, the entire contents of M but do not know how to do because I can not find a way to calculate the number of tables that make up the database that contains M.
I found this topic:

[Count the number of tables in the sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506527/count-the-number-of-tables-in-the-sqlite-database)

but I can not find "Cursor" and "getReadableDatabase."
Where can I download the latest version of SQLite for java?
I'm using the following version:

"sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-SNAPSHOT-2.jar"

---

If I write:

```
int numero_tabelle = 0;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").getInterfaces();
            String nome = "jdbc:sqlite:" + nome_database;
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(nome);
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'"); 
            //ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'");
            numero_tabelle = rs.getInt("sqlite_master");
            conn.close();
            rs.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException a) {
            System.out.println("Manca la libreria SQLITE.");
        } catch (SQLException b) {
            System.out.println(nome_database + " inesistente.");
            System.out.println("E' anche possibile "
                    + "che le risorse hardware siano insufficienti.");
        }
        System.out.println("Number of tables: " + numero_tabelle);
```

I get:

```
SuperM.sqlite inesistente.
E' anche possibile che le risorse hardware siano insufficienti.
Number of tables: 0
```

:(

Comment: `Cursor` and `getReadableDatabase` are Android APIs. Do you know how to execute queris with JDBC?

Comment: Yes I know code like this:
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + nome_tabella);
but it provides the number of record, not tables... :(
Must I import some .jar file besides sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-SNAPSHOT-2.jar to can using Cursor and getReadableDatabase?

Comment: But I must download this .jar file?!?!?
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I am not interested to android, I am programming on windows 8... :(

Answer (score 3):

Use following query to achieve your goal,

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name != 'android_metadata' AND name != 'sqlite_sequence';
```

It will return the count of table.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite has a system table [sqlite_master](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master), which contains a record for each database object.

To get the number of tables, execute a query like this:

```java
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'");
```

which will return one record for each table.

Alternatively, execute a query like this:

```java
rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'");
int tableCount = rs.getInt(1);
```

which will return one record with the number of tables.

Comment: Wawwwww!!!!!!!! yes!!!!!!!

Thanks very much! Why the right code is this?

rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'");
int tableCount = rs.getInt(1) -1;

??? Is sqlite_master the fist table?

Comment: No, I did not because it was too long for me and it was in English. I have some problems with your language, I speak fluently only Italian.